# Configuring Spring Eureka Client through environmental variables in CF

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, spring-cloud

Trying to get a older version of Spring Boot running on Pivotal Web Services.

It needs to connect to a Eureka server. I have stood up a new Eureka server in the same space the Client App is running on in PWS.

As I don't have the code for the Client application (can't modify the application property/yml files), I need to configure the Client's Eureka client to connect to the new Eureka server using Environmental Variables.

Here is what I have tried:

In the Cloud Foundries 'manifest.yml' I currently have:

```sh
---
applications:
- name: <Client application name>
  ...
  other non related settings
  ...
  env:
    EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME: https://<pws route of eureka server>
```

This is not picked up.

It looks like that property is picked up like that:
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/1.1.0.RELEASE/source-code/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java

I have tried a few variable names:

- eureka.instance.hostname
- EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE
- eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone

I also tried setting a SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON to contain these combinations in the same way in the manifest.yml.

None of them seem to get picked up.

Is there a different way that this can be done? Again, I don't have access to the code, only the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

So its not pretty, but I was able to modify the application.properties files in the Jars using VIM to contain this setting:

```sh
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=<pws route>/eureka/
```

Just made the Jar write-able, added that setting, saved and then cf push'd it up. Works. Not sure why the ENV did not work, but its not worth fixing. Everything in this Jar is ancient (Spring Cloud version 1.0). Its all going to get re-written anyway, just need the legacy version running somewhere stable while that work happens.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables:

```
  EUREKA_CLIENT_REGION=default
  EUREKA_CLIENT_AVAILABILITYZONES_DEFAULT=myzone
  EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_MYZONE=http://eureka:8761/eureka
```

EUREKA_CLIENT_REGION sets region to `default`

EUREKA_CLIENT_AVAILABILITYZONES_DEFAULT sets zone `myzone` for region `default` (suffix _DEFAULT)

EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_MYZONE sets server url for zone `myzone` (suffix _MYZONE)

These env variables are read into [EurekaClientConfigBean](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/main/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientConfigBean.java) and used in [EndpointUtils.getServiceUrlsFromConfig](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/bae5c36f37dd8838db83400fc46c8204d69ce6da/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/discovery/endpoint/EndpointUtils.java#L190)